_a.Socket is not a constructor
I have an electron app that should do with the TCP server and on my client side I had  this error"_a.Socket is not a constructor", after connecting to my server, the server worked normally, but the connection had issues, connection code below
var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(3000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
